# Quasi static process banch of sand on a piston (What happen if I am adding atmospheric pressure)

Tags: thermodynamics

I know the classic example for quasi static process with the banch of sand on a piston (neglecting the atmosphere pressure and friction). if we take 1 by 1 grain of sand, the process is quasi static.

My question is what happen if we are not neglecting the atmosphere pressure? I think the process of taking the grain of sand 1 by 1 will not be quasi static anymore because the effect of taking out the grains will depend on the height of the piston.

I think the key here is is to think if the temperture is really define between the process mini stages wich I need some help.

Comment: It’s still quasi static.  It’s the same as starting with more sand to begin with.

Comment: Ok I understand, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know the classic example for quasi static process with the batch of
> sand on a piston (neglecting the atmosphere pressure and friction). if
> we take 1 by 1 grain of sand, the process is quasi static.

The example applies regardless of whether or not atmospheric pressure is involved.

Atmospheric pressure simply adds a fixed value to the external pressure at the beginning and end of the process of adding or subtracting sane. As long as the sand is added or subtracted grain by grain the process is still quasi-static, regardless of any fixed value of external pressure at the beginning and end of the process, be it the atmosphere, or a fixed mass resting atop the piston.

Hope this helps.